# UiTableView Cell dynamic height not displaying properly in chat while sending message

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When i send image in chat, the dynamic height of tableview cell gets disturbed on every message when tableview reloads. If i don't send image in whole chat it is working fine. If i move close the view and get back to the chatroom tableview cell height and width is working fine. But when i send message view gets disturbed.

[image]

When is send message the UITableView cell gets disturbed.

[image]

I am using below code to build the sender cell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SenderCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SenderCell
cell.selectionStyle = .none

cell.configureCell(msg: (objVM?.messages?[indexPath.row])!)

return cell
```

Dynamic height of cell is adjusted by the below code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat  {
     if objVM?.messages?[indexPath.row].text ?? "" != "" {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
     } else {
        return 200
     }
 }
```

Comment: have you added the constraint to textField?

Comment: Yes! Constraint are added to the textfield. The cell inside the tableview exceeds its height that is making UI disturb.

Comment: Set Content Hugging Priority of you label to required